# Swings to EJB communication without RMI port

Tags: swing

I have swing based web application. Currently, the Swing clients communicates to EJB which is running in remote server through third party 'HTTP Tunneling' tool (JProxy). This is commercial tool.
my question is:

1. Is there any other open source / free 'HTTP Tunneling' tools equivalent to JProxy using which the Swing clients can communicate to EJB.
2. What are the ways a Swing client can communicate to EJB other than RMI protocal.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could create a Web Service to communicate to your backend

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service
- http://java.sun.com/webservices/

Comment: I want to look up an EJB and call the methods. I don't want to implement WebServices model. I am looking for any open source / free HTTP tunneling tool for Java / Swing.